# Getting the 3 consecutive year in Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have problem getting the year

I have here in my database year of 11/11/2016 - 11/13/2015 - 11/13/2014
the problem is I want to get that year just deducting current year
so if the current year is 2017 I want to get 2016,2015,2014 , and the next year
2018 the year will get is 2017,2016,2015

```
$selectmemberpaid = mysql_query("SELECT 

memberid,StartDate,EndDate,tblpayments.activityname,amount_paid FROM 

tblattend_activity LEFT JOIN tblpayments ON tblattend_activity.memberid = 

.profile_id WHERE memberid='201400001'");
```

That is my query..

and this is my while loop

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectmemberpaid)) {

    # code...
    $dateTimestamp = strtotime($rows['StartDate']);

    $year = date("Y", $dateTimestamp);


  }
```

Comment: Where is your code attempt ?

Comment: [Please read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show us your query and if possible , little more about your table, so others can understand well and give you proper answer.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: selectmemberpaid = mysql_query("SELECT memberid,StartDate,EndDate,tblpayments.activityname,amount_paid FROM tblattend_activity LEFT JOIN tblpayments ON tblattend_activity.memberid = tblpayments.profile_id WHERE memberid='201400001'"

Comment: It is consecutive brother

Answer (score 1):

You can get the year from a date string by doing something like this:

```
$dateTimestamp = strtotime('2015-12-12');
$year = date("Y", $dateTimestamp);
echo $year;
```

Once you get it you can add or subtract to get the previous/next year (after converting the value into an integer).

Comment: how to determine if the user have year of 2016,2015 if the database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking but:[image: Picture of DB]

Query!

```
        $rest = substr(date('d-m-Y'), 6);       
        $rep = $idz->query("SELECT * FROM stack1 where SUBSTR(date_depart, 6) < $rest 
        order by SUBSTR(date_depart,6) desc limit 3");
        while ($row = $rep->fetch())
        {
        echo  $row['date_depart'];
        //echo "<br>";
        }
        $rep->closeCursor();
```

Result

[image]

Comment: The problem i have is, if the user paid at 2016 , 2015 it will echo good. ,   if the user paid only 2015 not 2016 it will echo bad. so it depends on the year today. so if year today is 2017 the program search the consecutive 2 years. the 2016 , 2015. if the year today is 2018 the program search 2017,2016